# Turning Test-Connection error into a message

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following code to get the status and IP addresses of machines in a list:

```
    $csv = Get-Content TEST_MACHINES.csv

    foreach ($computer in $csv)
    {
try
{
    Test-Connection $computer -Count 1 | Select-Object Address, IPV4Address
}
catch [System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException]
{
    '$computer is offline.'
}
    }
```

The objective is to get the IP address of each machine, and if the machine is offline print "$computer is offline."

However instead of catching the error and displaying the message, it displays the whole Test-Connection error.  How do I get it to only display my message when there's an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a `Try/Catch`, the `Catch` block is only invoked on terminating errors.  Add `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Test-Connection` to force the errors to be terminating so the `Catch` block will run:

```
Test-Connection $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object Address, IPV4Address
```

Comment: Commenting here to mention that the `Try/Catch` won't terminate on the error when `Test-Connection -Quiet` is used.